# Alignment of caption in Listing

Tags: listings

i need help with the alignment of my caption. The Problem is that the second line dont align correct.

[image]

My code is:

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing} {\parbox{\textwidth}{\hspace{15pt}#1#2#3} } 
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing, singlelinecheck=true, margin=0pt, font={small}}`
```

and

```
`\lstset {
frame=shadowbox,
rulesepcolor=\color{mylightgrey},
showspaces=false,showtabs=false,tabsize=2,
 %numberstyle=\tiny,numbers=left,
 numberstyle=\scriptsize,numbers=left,
 numberstyle=\color{mylightgrey},
 basicstyle=\scriptsize\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont,
 stringstyle=\color{sh_string},
 keywordstyle = \color{sh_keyword}\bfseries,
 keywordstyle=\bfseries,
 commentstyle=\color{sh_comment}\itshape,
 captionpos=b,
 xleftmargin=0.7cm, xrightmargin=0.5cm,
 %lineskip=-0.3em,
 escapebegin={\lstsmallmath}, escapeend={\lstsmallmathend}
}`
```

Comment: Try changing `margin=0pt` to `margin=15pt` and drop the `format=listing` (since your caption format `listing` is the culprit here.)

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!